# Why my function having vector array as parameter not giving any value?

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

```
void plusMinus(vector<int> arr) {
    double p=0, n=0, z=0;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++)
        if(arr[i]>0)
            p += 1/arr.size();
        else if(arr[i]<0)
            n += 1/arr.size();
        else
            z += 1/arr.size();
    cout<<p<<endl<<n<<endl<<z;
}
```

The values of p, n, and z are not changing in the for loop. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

You do `1/arr.size()` in the function. The result is an integer with the value `0`.

You need to use at least one `double` in the division.

Example:

```
p += 1. / arr.size();
```

Do the same for `n` and `z` too.